# Where and how often do I have to enable Offline Capabilities of Firebase in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app with many different fragments that use different types of Firebase Realtime Database actions (Queries, LiveData, writeOperations) on different nodes. Now I would like to enable offline capabilities on the real-time database such that queries, livedata and write operations are executed even if the device losses internet connection. In the official documentation, it is written that I just have to use the following code (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities?hl=en):

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

Now my question is where and how often do I have to use this line? Do I have to use it before each of the firebase operations (queries, LiveData, writeOperations) in every Java class, or do I only need it once in the MainActivity class or do I need it once per Fragment (maybe in the onCreate method)? And do I just need this one line of code or do I also need the other stuff mentioned on the site (like Keeping Data Fresh, Querying Data Offline, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's right. You only have to use:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

> Now my question is where and how often do I have to use this line?

You can add that line of code, directly to your code, when the application starts. So you might consider creating a class that extends Application:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

But be careful to only call setPersistenceEnabled before you have called getReference() for the first time.

Regarding how often, you only need to call it once.

> Do I have to use it before each of the firebase operations (queries, LiveData, writeOperations) in every Java class

No. By default, it caches all the databases. So if you perform different operations in different places in your application, all those operations are cached. Besides that, there is no way you can only cache partial data. It's all the database or nothing.

> And do I just need this one line of code or do I also need the other stuff mentioned on the site (like Keeping Data Fresh, Querying Data Offline, etc.)?

You only need that line of code.

Comment: Thanks Alex for your answer. I have to follow-up questions to it. 1) Why do I have to add your suggested code into the Android Manifest? On the offical site nothing is mentioned regarding the Manifest as far as I see it. 2) You wrote "But be careful to only call setPersistenceEnabled before you have called getReference() for the first time." --> Do I have to call the setPersistenceEnabled  before  getReference in every Fragment of the app or just in the main activity class?

Comment: 1. You have to define the name of the application. And this should be performed in the AndroidManifest file, otherwise is not needed. 2. You need to call setPersistenceEnabled only once, either in activity or in the class I showed you in my answer.

Comment: Thanks Alex for your answer and effort. I really appreciate it. I have to admit that I still don't understand your point about the manuscript. Independant from Firebase I have a Manuscript that contains the name of the App (this is required for every Android app as far as I understand). In my current manuscript the following line that you suggested is missing `android:allowBackup="false"` whereas the rest is available. So I don't really understand why I have to change the manuscript. Can I just leave it as it especially considering that nothing is mentioned on the offical site

Comment: That was just an example. For sure you can leave it as it is and according to the use case of your app. The official docs say what you have to do, not how you should do it. So you should choose how to do it. I was just provided a possible solution.

Comment: Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try it later but maybe you can remove the part with the manuscript because it might be confussing for others (for me it's still highly confussing especially considering that this is not mentioned on the official Firebase documentation about Enabling Offline Capabilities in Firebase). If you don't need it then it's better not to mentione it as it will just increase the complexity without having any benefits (and I don't see any of them)

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer. Looking forward to seeing your feedback.

Comment: Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Thanks Alex for your help. I checked it and it works fine. I accepted and upvoted your answer.